# How to get specific columns using fetchXML Query

Tags: reporting-services, report, fetchxml

I have created a report for weekly comment but everytime if i add comment and run report its coming with new column.
for example first time i need 4 columns for weekly report and its generating correctly but if we add comment and run report then it will come with 5 column for weekly comment and if we will add 1 more comment then it will come with 6 column for weekly comment, and so on.Any help will be appreciated

```
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="_projectcontrolsheet">
    <attribute name="_supportstartfrom" />
    <attribute name="_supportendson" />
    <attribute name="_warrantydescription" />
    <attribute name="_penaltydeadline" />
    <attribute name="_ispenaltyavoided" />
    <attribute name="_penaltyclause" />
    <attribute name="_isanyescalationraised" />
    <attribute name="_escalationraisedto" />
    <attribute name="_escalationdescription" />
    <attribute name="_istrainingrequired" />
    <attribute name="_projectcontrolsheetid" />
    <attribute name="_contactpersonnumber" />
    <order attribute="projectnumber" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="pcsweeklycomments" from="weeklycommentsid" to="projectcontrolsheetid" visible="false" alias="aj" link-type="outer">
       <attribute name="weeklycommentsid" />  
      <attribute name="name" />
       <attribute name="createdby" />
      <attribute name="createdon" />
      <attribute name="weeklycommentdescription" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Following are Text Box Properties in Weekly Comments column

```
=IIf(ISNOTHING(Fields!aj_createdon.Value), "-", "Comment Date:" +Fields!aj_createdon.Value+ "<br/>Comment by : " +Fields!aj_createdby.Value+"<br />Comment Summary:" +Fields!aj_abn_name.Value+ "<br/>Comment Description : "+Fields!aj_abn_weeklycommentdescription.Value )
```

and i am Using Matrix

[image]

Comment: Few questions:
1. Is your comment a field? I mean everytime new comment is added a data is saved to new field. For ex: comment 1 -> filed 1, comment 2-> field 2 and so on.
2. From your Fetch I see your abcweeklycomments is a child entity for abcprojectcontrolsheet. Does that mean every time you add a comment a new Record is created?
3.Also with the above fetch do you get all your comments or you cannot show newly created comments?

Comment: yes everytime i adding comment, a comment is coming with a new column.But i want comment should be in same column.

Comment: ok Did you added all your comments field in your fetch, I mean if you have 10 fields did you get all the 10 fields in your fetch?
Also you could use SSRS column visible function to show only those column which contains data.

Comment: yes i have did this as well.in the image above i am trying to get 4 columns named 'Weekly Comments' but everytime when i added new comment and run report then comment is coming with a new column.as u can see 7 columns are there for Weekly Comment

Comment: Answers to ur questions :-1 yes comment a field.2.yes every timei add a comment a new column created.3 i am getting all comments newly + old ones but i need only last 4 new ones.Thanks for help in advance